# is there XSS risk when a page outputs 500 error?

Tags: java, xss

I worked on a website in China last year. THe website has been running fine, but I just received an email fromNetwork Security Bureau in China.

They sent me an attachment along with a few URLs. one of them is

http://mydomain.com/servlets/pdf?var=xss<audio src=pksovf onerror=pksovf(qrx)>

They say that the above url has a risk. I checked the url and it throws 500 error all the time because the url format is incorrect.

if a page throws a 500 error, is there still a risk? I don't think so, but I just want to confirm.

Comment: How could there be? You wouldn't even get to see the page, right?

Comment: @woz, true but some webservers just spit the errors which may give useful information to the hacker such as revealing of the code, tables names , etc

Comment: @sh4nx0r True, but that's not really an XSS attack.

Comment: @woz // that's exactly what I thought, but it's coming from Network Security Bureau..so..I'm lost here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potentially *yes*. It depends where the error occured.

If your back-end *did* inserted this string in a database somewhere before crashing, that may be queried later on to render this string in one of your view, this could be dramatically dangerous as an attacker could potentially insert arbitrary HTML or Javascript in a webpage and redirect for exemple a user to a harmful website.

Also, this could easily result in an [`SQL injection`](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) if a database was queried with this string at some point, given that it was not filtered.

To summarize, it depends on what your did with this string and *where* did your code crash.

Anyway, you should not have this kind of issues and should always check the validity of a user input. Getting a `500` HTTP return code is exceptional and means that something went *wrong* on the server side. You got to fix this anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A 500 is roughly analogous to a crash in a piece of desktop software.  Crashes are considered security risks because they can be exploited by malicious inputs, and the same could be said of the web server.

A 500 means "something we weren't expecting happened, and we failed to deal with it."  That means there's something there that could be exploited - there's no guarantee of that, just like there's no guarantee that a crash in a piece of desktop software can be exploited, but it's correct to treat both of those cases as potential security holes.